# Where would printer ink go in Statement of Business Activites for tax?

Tags: income-tax, canada, contractor

I'm an independent contractor. I bought printer ink for the printer I use exclusively for work. On the T2125 where would it go? I'm guessing either lines 8810 or 8811: "office expenses", or "supplies".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [CRA page about T2125 business expenses](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/sole-proprietorships-partnerships/report-business-income-expenses/completing-form-t2125/expenses-section-form-t2125.html) shows this about [Line 8810 - Office Expenses](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/sole-proprietorships-partnerships/report-business-income-expenses/completing-form-t2125/line-8810-office-expenses.html):

> You can deduct the cost of **office expenses**. These include small items such as:
>
> - pens
> - pencils
> - paper clips
> - stationery
> - stamps

For [Line 8811 - Office Stationary and Supplies](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/sole-proprietorships-partnerships/report-business-income-expenses/completing-form-t2125/line-8811-supplies.html), it says:

> You can deduct the cost of items the business used to provide goods or services for example, drugs and medication used by a veterinarian or cleaning supplies used by a plumber. If you run a daycare, these include household supplies that children use and food you buy to feed the children.

It’s a fine line, but from what I can tell, 8810 is specifically for supplies you would use or consume in a business office, and 8811 is for supplies that would be consumed in the production of your product or the providing of your service.

Depending on what your business does, printer ink could go either way. For most businesses, printer ink should probably be in 8810, but if you are a printing company, ink would make sense in 8811.

Comment: The issue that I have with including toner in 8810 is that the toner, at least OEM toner, is comparatively expensive and the CRA's description specifically mentions **small** items. This begs the question: Is the CRA using 'small' to describe the physical object or the expense itself? Based on the example provided, it seems to be describing the expense itself as opposed to the physical object. It is still ambiguous nonetheless in my opinion. I wish the CRA would be more specific.

Comment: @oldboy If you are in doubt, you need to ask your accountant.  But in my very unprofessional opinion, printer ink/toner is an office expense.  It is a consumable that is not a depreciable capital asset, and is needed in the office of every business.

Comment: @oldboy small is relative…

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica its certainly not a capital asset/cost. the only ambiguity is which class it falls in as a current expense. most accountants are clueless and youre still accountable for their mistakes if they make any so whats the point? lol

Comment: @RonJohn ofc, but relative to the value or the object. it seems like its relative to the value

Comment: @oldboy If you think accountants, who handle this stuff all the time, are clueless, what do you think of strangers on the internet?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica a lot of accountants dont deal with this stuff specifically on a regular basis. this is only a small part of fiscal practice.

Comment: @oldboy Proper accountants, like many professionals, have malpractice insurance (a.k.a. errors and omissions insurance). If they screw up bad, you can make a claim against them.

Comment: @oldboy Something you might be missing here: All of these business expenses from the different lines on the T2125 get added together on the form. It really doesn’t matter if you choose to put toner on one line and another business owner puts it on a different line. The result is the same, and no one will care.

Comment: @user71659 i didnt know that! thx for sharing!

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica the govt and cra are sticklers. surely, if there are amounts that are unusual in degree and or position according to the CRA, it could trigger some sort of response